# それぞれの列の値が、文面に含まれているかを判定する

Tags: python, python3, pandas

それぞれの列の値が、文面に含まれているかを判定するには、どうすればよいでしょうか？

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(
    data={
        'コンテキスト': ['東京は晴れ', '曇りの神奈川', '熱い沖縄の気候'],
        'キーワード': ['福岡', '神奈川', '沖縄']},
    index=['xx', 'yy', 'zz']
)
display(df)
```

```
# それぞれの列の値が、文面に含まれているかを判定するには、どうすればよいでしょうか？
# ループしなければならないものでしょうか。pd.Series.str.contains()の引数にSeriesが指定できるとよいのですが。。
print('◇期待する結果')
expedted_df = pd.DataFrame(
    data={
        'コンテキスト': ['東京は晴れ', '曇りの神奈川', '熱い沖縄の気候'],
        'キーワード': ['福岡', '神奈川', '沖縄'],
        'Flag': [False, True, True]
    },
    index=['xx', 'yy', 'zz']
)
display(expedted_df)
```

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Numpy の `vectorize()` を使う例。

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(
    data={
        'コンテキスト': ['東京は晴れ', '曇りの神奈川', '熱い沖縄の気候'],
        'キーワード': ['福岡', '神奈川', '沖縄']},
    index=['xx', 'yy', 'zz']
)

df['flag'] = np.vectorize(lambda ctx, kw: kw in ctx)(*df.T.values)
print(df)
```

|  | コンテキスト | キーワード | flag |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| xx | 東京は晴れ | 福岡 | False |
| yy | 曇りの神奈川 | 神奈川 | True |
| zz | 熱い沖縄の気候 | 沖縄 | True |

Comment: ありがとうございます。期待した結果が得られました。
100万行のDataFrameで試したところ、df.applyは14.7sec、np.vectorizeは4.9secでした。

Answer (score 1):

ほぼループに近いけどこんな感じに記述できます

```py
df['flag'] = df.apply(lambda s: s['キーワード'] in s['コンテキスト'], axis=1)
display(df)
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。期待した結果が得られました。